Boxplot with mean and variance
I have a intersection data with intersection id, number of vehicles in low and high traffic based in intersection id. So basically three values- intersection id, vehicles in low traffic and vehicles in high traffic. I want to plot mean and variance of specific intersection id with low and high traffic using boxplot with intersection id as x axis label. How to do that?
I have created csv file with field '1HT,1LT,2HT,2LT' where 1,2 are intersection id. Do I need to change csv file format also?
I have used this code:

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

df=pd.read_csv("name1.csv")
print(df)

means=df.mean()
var=df.var()
q1=means+ var * stats.norm.ppf(0.25)
q3=means+ var * stats.norm.ppf(0.75)

whislow = q1 - (q3-q1) *1.5
whishi = q1 + (q3-q1) *1.5
cl=df.columns
print("cl",cl)
plt.xticks(range(1,len(df.columns)+1),cl,rotation='vertical')
keys = ['med','q1','q3','whislo','whishi']
stats = [dict(zip(keys,vals)) for vals in zip(means,q1,q3,whislow,whishi)]
plt.subplot().bxp(stats,showfliers=False)
plt.show()

I am able to create a boxplot, but the column name does not work.
I want '1HT, 1LT, 2HT, and 2LT' as column IDs with the mean and variance of low/high traffic.

"Not working" isn't helpful. Code that can't be run isn't helpful. But you seem to set your ticks, and then create a subplot on top of that - try setting ticks at the end.

I would always adjust the csv data to the columns: intersection, traffic_type and number_of_vehicles. Every line should be an unique entry.
You can use this format to pivot the table, and flatten it so you can easily plot with it.
pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index='Intersection_ID', columns='Traffic_Type', values='Number_of_Vehicles', aggfunc=['mean', 'var'])

# Flatten the multi-level column index for easier plotting
pivot_df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in pivot_df.columns.values]

Then I would use that to plot the boxplot using the box plot from pandas:
# Create boxplot for mean and variance
boxplot_data = pivot_df[['mean_Low', 'mean_High', 'var_Low', 'var_High']]
boxplot_data.plot(kind='box', subplots=False, layout=(1,4))

To show the plot with correct labels:
# Set x-axis labels
plt.xticks(range(1, len(boxplot_data.columns) + 1), boxplot_data.columns, rotation='vertical')

plt.title('Boxplot of Mean and Variance of Traffic by Intersection')
plt.ylabel('Number of Vehicles')
plt.show()


Hi, thanks for your reply however I am getting this error:
KeyError: "None of [Index(['mean_Low', 'mean_High', 'var_Low', 'var_High'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
